# jQuery: Get all text inputs where no type is defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When i use `$("input[type=text]")` i absolutely mean all text boxes but it only return inputs that type has been set for them.

For example in:

```
<input name="text1" />
<input name="text2' type="text"/>
```

`text1` is not included.

how to get all text inputs regardless type has been set or not ?

Comment: well technically an input is only a text input if you say type="text"

Comment: I see, but when we don't set any type it will be shown as "text" by default

Comment: yes and it seems to validate, you could use the answer about the name as long as your name attribute has the "text" or you can always do it the long way say match all inputs except radio, submit, checkbox and whatever else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selects the ones with type=text, and the ones without type attribute.

```
$("input[type=text],input:not([type])")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input:text')
```

[From the official documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

> As of jQuery 1.5.2, :text selects input elements that have no
>   specified type attribute (in which case type="text" is implied).

Comment: `:text` selector is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter` method:

```
$("input").filter(function(){
    return this.type === 'text'
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hgzmQ/

Answer (score 0):

if all of the names of your inputs are contain 'text' in them (otherwise how would you understand that it's a text box?), you could try.

```
$('input[name*="text"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the type, then [type="text"] will preclude the ones without type.

if you select $('input') you will get every input regardless of type, so that could be a text field, or not. but it would still apply to every input field.

If you don't set the type, it won't be shown as type=text, but it will be rendered as such. That means you can't select JUST [type="text"], but you could always preclude others though as follows:

```
$('input[type=text]','input:not([type])')
```

Not sure if this helps at all.