# How to select all the inputs and textareas except for the ones with type=password

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Until now I was using this selector successfully:

```
$('input, textarea')
```

But the problem is this also selects the inputs with `type=password`

[I know I can select something like this:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12866974/463065)

```
$("input[type=text],input:not([type]),textarea")
```

But what about other types?

I want to select all inputs that haven't the type attribute set to `password`.

I was trying to use the `:not` selector but couldn't use it successfully.

```
$("input:not(:password)")
```

Didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

Like this :

```
$("input[type!='password'], textarea")
```

Comment: That easy huh? Damn, I'm sort of ashamed of not thinking of that! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('input:not([type="password"]), textarea')
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery does not have a `:password` selector.

Instead, you can use the [`attributeNotEqual` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

```
$(':input[type!="password"]')
```

Note this example also uses the [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/), which selects all input types, including `textarea` and `select` elements.